# Json.stringfy shows strange string when used with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, string

I have a simple collection of divs called `myDivs`. The program iterates over it, copies its elements into another array, `s`, and then stringifies it, but I get a strange string...

```
var s = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
    var div = get(i);
    console.log(div); // console shows div properly.
    s.push(div);    
}
var q = JSON.stringify(s); // q shows [{"jQuery1124028777031728586544":14}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the `q` string to be?

Comment: What is the content of `myDivs`? What does the `get()` function return?

Comment: A wild guess is that you're trying to stringify jQuery objects containing DOM nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your array "myDivs" is a jquery object with objects and functions, so JSON.stringify can not convert it to JSON and shows "{" jQuery1124028777031728586544 ": 14}"

Check the structure of your array "myDivs"

(Sorry my English, but do not speak english.)